# Git Templates not working correctly for unknown reasons

Tags: git

I cloned a repository and it complained `warning: templates not found in '~/.git_template'`, which is the directory my `init.templatedir` is configured to. There are definitely things in there though.

```bash
$ find ~/.git_template
/home/abrahms/.git_template
/home/abrahms/.git_template/templates
/home/abrahms/.git_template/templates/something
/home/abrahms/.git_template/hooks
/home/abrahms/.git_template/hooks/pre-hook
```

I thought perhaps `~` expansion was broken, but replacing `init.templatedir` with `/home/abrahms/.git_template` didn't change anything.

Potentially useful shell output:

```bash
[nix-shell:~/src/github.com/XAMPPRocky/XAMPPRocky]$ gh repo clone XAMPPRocky/octocrab
Cloning into 'octocrab'...
warning: templates not found in '~/.git_template'
remote: Enumerating objects: 3017, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (997/997), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (179/179), done.
remote: Total 3017 (delta 869), reused 883 (delta 815), pack-reused 2020
Receiving objects: 100% (3017/3017), 730.71 KiB | 2.91 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2146/2146), done.

[nix-shell:~/src/github.com/XAMPPRocky/XAMPPRocky]$ find ~/.git_template
/home/abrahms/.git_template
/home/abrahms/.git_template/templates
/home/abrahms/.git_template/templates/something
/home/abrahms/.git_template/hooks
/home/abrahms/.git_template/hooks/pre-hook

[nix-shell:~/src/github.com/XAMPPRocky/XAMPPRocky]$ nano ~/.gitconfig

[nix-shell:~/src/github.com/XAMPPRocky/XAMPPRocky]$ rm -rf octocrab/

[nix-shell:~/src/github.com/XAMPPRocky/XAMPPRocky]$ gh repo clone XAMPPRocky/octocrab
Cloning into 'octocrab'...
warning: templates not found in '/home/abrahms/.git_template'
remote: Enumerating objects: 3017, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1018/1018), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (256/256), done.
remote: Total 3017 (delta 830), reused 864 (delta 758), pack-reused 1999
Receiving objects: 100% (3017/3017), 749.60 KiB | 3.92 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2109/2109), done.

[nix-shell:~/src/github.com/XAMPPRocky/XAMPPRocky]$ find /home/abrahms/.git_template
/home/abrahms/.git_template
/home/abrahms/.git_template/templates
/home/abrahms/.git_template/templates/something
/home/abrahms/.git_template/hooks
/home/abrahms/.git_template/hooks/pre-hook

[nix-shell:~/src/github.com/XAMPPRocky/XAMPPRocky]$ git config init.templatedir
'/home/abrahms/.git_template'
```